# catplot() in seaborn doesn't work with subplot()

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I cannot subplot catplot. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.catplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=df , kind='violin')
sns.catplot(x='species', y='sepal_width', data=df , kind='violin')
```

And here is the output:
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catplot` creates its [own new figure](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html). You can either use `catplot` on a ["long form dataframe"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) (using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)), or create individual `sns.violinplot`s on each `ax`.

Using subplots with `violinplot`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.violinplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=df, ax=axes[0])
sns.violinplot(x='species', y='sepal_width', data=df, ax=axes[1])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Using `catplot` with long form dataframe:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='species', value_vars=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width'])

sns.catplot(x='species', y='value', col='variable', data=df_long, kind='violin')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with long form dataframe]

Answer (score 4):

Although this may be a promotion of my package, [patchworklib](https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib) allows you to handle catplot plots as matplotlib subplots.
Please see the following code.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import patchworklib as pw
pw.overwrite_axisgrid()

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g1 = sns.catplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=df , kind='violin')
g1 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g1)

g2 = sns.catplot(x='species', y='sepal_width', data=df , kind='violin')
g2 = pw.load_seaborngrid(g2) 

(g1|g2).savefig()
```

[image]

You can also align them vertically as follow.

```py
(g1/g2).savefig()
```

[image]

The code above is executable in [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hi-H-ABQ6A3DpZZMwIMUBFyZlIBSwYBe?usp=sharing).